# Coldfusion can't see table 'Helpers', but CAN see other tables in same database. Any ideas

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I'm running CF 2016, SQL Server free edition 2017.

For the life of me I cannot figure this out or find similar issue. I've deleted the table 'Helpers' and re-created it and named it 'Helper'. But, it made no difference.  I used a query to create it the first time. Then used designer when recreating it. I ran a query to auto-increment on both since I have yet to see a spot to select that when creating.

Since creating a new replica table made no difference I'm back to using the original table. If it can grab data from other tables in the same database, what could possibly prevent this table from having a query from CF run on it? Yes, obviously the data source has been created and verified by CF Administrator and is named "Helpers". The query in SQL server for same data on this table works.

I know it might seem odd that the table is named 'Helpers' while the DB is named the same, but as I said, it made no difference when it had a different name. Besides, it's all letters to the systems.  For what it's worth, it's the last table I made out of a lot of tables.
Would greatly appreciate any ideas.

I'm totally stalled here.

Thanks.

> Error Executing Database Query.  [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC
>   Driver][SQLServer]Invalid object name 'Helpers'.
>
> The error occurred in
>   C:/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot/helpers/displayLocations.cfm: line
>   22 20 : #getState.City# 21 :  22 :  23 :   SELECT * 24 :   FROM
>   Helpers

Comment: Correction:  I didn't delete the original table.  I was about to, but didn't.  And yes, I changed the table name in the query when using the second one...then changed it back when I decided to revert to original.

Comment: Why are you editing my post?  I did not intend to say out of "a lot" of tables.  I meant out of "the "lot"" of tables.  "Lot" means a bunch, group etc.

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  Run a cfquery that gets all the table names from that database and see what's there.  There are lots of code samples for that, right here, on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ... and verify which database the query is running against.

Comment: I created a brand new table named: "Permissions".  Tested in SQL server, as in ran query to select all. It works.  Can't see this table either.

Comment: Here is code: <cfquery name="getPermission" datasource="Helpers">
  SELECT *
  FROM Permissions
 </cfquery>
........................................  Then attempting to output that query.  <cfoutput>
 Username: #getPermission.Username#, Password: #getPermission.Password#
</cfoutput>     Subsequent Error on CF page (can't see this table either)

Comment: So, TBL 'Zip_Codes_All' is the only TBL that can be seen or accessed by CF.  I've created 3 new tables.  They can be queried in Sql Server, and return results.  .................Something broke.  I'm thinking maybe it's a SQL sever problem at this point.  It makes no sense.

Comment: Just for grins try using `select somecolumn` instead of `select *`.  You didn't say what happened when you compared the credentials, current database and tables, like Dan suggested? (Use the system views..) " It makes no sense" That kind of thing would make sense if the two tools were using different schemas or credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: This wasn't a syntax error or wrong DB problem.  It appears that the SQL Server needed "Intellisense Cache" refreshed.  I never heard of this and it seems like it should do this on it's own.  But a DBA suggested the refresh, and it worked. Edit-->Intellisense-->Refresh.  It worked.  Now CF can see the tables...!  Days I spent on this.  I think I hate SQL server now. Much appreciate everyone who tried to help.  Maybe this will help others.  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/how-to-refresh-the-local-intellisense-ca/

Comment: Is this using the built in Adobe drivers to connect? That's very odd... wasn't aware intellisense impacted anything other than SSMS. Can the DBA explain why it might affect outside connections?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if it's Adobe drivers. But I assume so.  It's whatever is installed by default.  I selected SQL server when setting up the datasource to SQL server within CFAdmin.  The dba was online...see link above.  It was a blog post.

Comment: That's the Adobe drivers then.  Yeah, I saw the blog entry above, but always thought it was some special cache used by Intellisense only. Never heard about it being used by others tools for metadata, and didn't find much online, so if it is ... that's good to know.

Answer (score 2):

It will be helpful to understand the issue if you post your code.

From the information you provided, I can suggest you to try adding schema name to the table in your query.  i.e. if your helpers table is in dbo schema, instead of

```
SELECT column_name FROM helpers
```

try

```
SELECT column_name FROM dbo.helpers
```

Comment: Along those lines, two of the most common causes of not being able to "see" a table are a) using a different db than you *think* you're using in ssms. vs cfquery.  b) using different credentials with different object access.

Comment: I thought I was the only one stupid enough to query the wrong database.

Comment: Ok, tried that to no avail.  "Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid object name 'Helpers.HelperOrgName'." The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot/helpers/displayLocations.cfm: line 9
7 : 
8 : 
9 : <cfquery name="getLocation" datasource="Helpers">
10 :   SELECT *
11 :   FROM Helpers.HelperOrgName </cfquery>     ...................

Comment: Your query seems to be incorrect.  As per your question helpers is your table, not schema. Also, looks like HelperOrgName is the column name.  Try <cfquery name="getLocation" datasource="Helpers">SELECT HelperOrgName from Helpers </cfquery>

Comment: Another thing to check is, your ColdFusion administrator or application.cfc to make sure your database is configured correctly and the credentials are correct.